# c++ right way to initialize a vector of a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

i searched a lot here, but there is no right explanation for me, for an advanced newbie in c++. I worked before with vector of structs  and now I get segmentation faults...

Thats why I want to know how such objects actually works and if it is the right the way I am doing!

I have a struct like

```
struct numberOfSpecies {
   int predator;
   int prey1;
   int prey2;
};
```

and a vector of it:

```
std::vector<numberOfSpecies> size;
```

Before I resize it and fill it with values.

```
size.resize(100);
```

what is actually this doing? Is this right for a struct?
It looks like it is initialized with zeros...

Now I am doing this like:

```
size[t].predator=0;
size[t].prey1=0;
size[t].prey2=0;

for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k){
  size[t].predator++;
  size[t].prey1++;
  size[t].prey2++;
}
```

Is this right? Where are possible issues? How to do it better?

Comment: resize creates `n` number of structs but yours are only initialized by 0 on accident (because you use debug mode). You should assume each value has a random undefined value after resize the way you use it.

Comment: OK for helping: what is value is `t`? Where does the segmentation fault occur? could you please add a bit more code? Preferably in a  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve way

Comment: @Hayt are you sure for initialization at 0 is an accident ? I always think that resize calls constructor of object, so in this case, default one, which put every member to 0

Comment: @Garf365 No. the default constructor does not put every value at 0. Never. Only if you explicitly tell it to do. This behavior will be done when you compile your program with DEBUG flags. But on release this does not happen. basic types which are no classes (like int, double, pointer) have no default constructor and thus have an undefined value.

Comment: `for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k){ size[t].predator++;`: is it a typo `k` vs `t` ?

Comment: @Hayt: `std::vector` will *value-initialize* the structure and not *default-initialize* the structure. So for POD, it is zero-initialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 ah you are right. forgot the value initialization there instead of default one. Though still the statement `resize calls constructor of object` is not necessarily true. But yeah in case of the POD struct they are 0 everytime.

Comment: what do you want each element of the array to contain at the end of initialisation?

Comment: I think you mean "aggregate", not "struct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and 'correct' solution here is probably to just use the `resize()` function that belongs to the vector object with aggregate initialization (if you have access to c++11 and on), something like

```
size.resize(100,{0,0,0}); //aggregate initialization 

for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
{
    size[t].predator++;
    size[t].prey1++;
    size[t].prey2++;
}
```

All members of each `numberOfSpecies` object will be initialized to 0.

Comment: An "in-between" alternative would be `reserve` and `push_back`. But if you want to initialize everything with default values `resize` is better here.

Comment: I don't think you need the `{0,0,0}` (although it doesn't hurt) as the second argument of `resize`, as by default `std::vector::resize` performs default-initialization, which, for aggregates, means [zero-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: @vsoftco I've just included it to show the syntax, in-case for whatever reason he would want to initialize a member to a different value or for if anyone else looks up the question.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
size[t].predator=0;
size[t].prey1=0;
size[t].prey2=0;
```

will write zeros to the `t`th element of `size` - that may or may not be useful:

This:

```
for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k){
  size[t].predator++;
  size[t].prey1++;
  size[t].prey2++;
}
```

will increment the `t`th element of `size` N times.  This seems incredibly unlikely to be useful.  I think what you want is:

```
size[0].predator=0;  // Technically not needed because .resize()
size[0].prey1=0;     // will have initialized it to zero anyway
size[0].prey2=0;     // *BUT* explicit is always better than implicit.

// Initialize each element of size to be one greater than previous.
for(int k = 1; k < N; ++k){
  size[k].predator = size[k-1].predator + 1;
  size[k].prey1    = size[k-1].prey1    + 1;
  size[k].prey2    = size[k-1].prey2    + 1;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the value parameter for static parameters.

```
#include <vector>

struct foo{
    int g;
    int h;
    int l;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<foo> manyFoo(10, {0});
    manyFoo.resize(60, {0});
}
```

If you want to grow your vector as you also put arbitrary values into the struct you could ->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct foo{
    foo(int aG,int aH, int aL):g(aG),h(aH),l(aL) {};
    int g;
    int h;
    int l;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> lVec;
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        lVec.emplace_back(foo(i,i*2,i*4));
    }
    int lPos=0;
    for (auto &rFoo: lVec) {
        std::cout << "Item pos" << lPos++ << " g:" << rFoo.g << " h:" << rFoo.h << " l:" << rFoo.l << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you know the size of the vector and you want to populate it you could ->

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct foo{
    foo(int aG,int aH, int aL):g(aG),h(aH),l(aL) {};
    int g;
    int h;
    int l;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<foo> lVec(10,{0,0,0});
    int lPos = 0;
    for (auto &rFoo: lVec) {
        rFoo = foo(lPos,lPos*2,lPos*4);
        lPos++;
    }
    lPos=0;
    for (auto &rFoo: lVec) {
        std::cout << "Item pos" << lPos++ << " g:" << rFoo.g << " h:" << rFoo.h << " l:" << rFoo.l << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add an default constructor to your structure. The new code will look something like this:

```
struct numberOfSpecies {
    numberOfSpecies (): predator(0), prey1(0), prey2(0) { }  // default constructor
    int predator;
    int prey1;
    int prey2;
};
```

That way, your structure will be properly initialized inside your vector when resize is applied.

Comment: Or, with c++11 : `struct numberOfSpecies {
    int predator = 0;
    int prey1 = 0;
    int prey2 = 0;
};`

Comment: According "properly initialized", it's also true without constructor. Your constructor only explicit 0, but according `resize` specification, it's already properly initialized to zero inside vector. It's only interesting if you want other than 0 value by default

Comment: @Garf365 Or, since at least C++03, just leave the constructor out because it makes no difference in this case :-)